# ASP.NET Web API [FromForm] custom binding for list of objects property does not work from Postman, but does with Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have a controller method to accept multipart/form-data request with primitive types, File and List of objects. I saw that I need custom model binder when I have complex data type using FromForm and I made one, but the problem is that binding works from Swagger, but not from Postman.

Here is my controller method first:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] AddRequest addRequest)
 {
    var result = await _service.AddAsync(addRequest);
    if (result.Success)
     {
        return Ok(result);
     }
    return BadRequest();
 }
```

My request looks like this:

```
 public class AddRequest
 {
   public string? Name { get; set; }
   public string? Description { get; set;}
   public IFormFile? File { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<LocaleViewModel>? Locales { get; set; }
 }
```

And here is my viewmodel:

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MetadataValueModelBinder))]
public class LocaleViewModel
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Code { get; set; }
 }
```

And finally model binder:

```
 public class MetadataValueModelBinder : IModelBinder
 {
      public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
      {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            var values = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

            if (values.Length == 0)
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

            var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(values.FirstValue, bindingContext.ModelType, options);

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(deserialized);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
 }
```

So, when I fire request from Swagger, binding is done correctly and model name is Locales, but when I do it from Postman or my SPA, binding is not working and model name is Locales[0]. Am I missing something in my model binder or I'm doing everything completely wrong?

I was trying to understand how ValueProvider.GetValue works but with no success.

Comment: Gives us a screenshot and the "POST" contents from Postman, this should elucidate the question. You could also post the CURL generated by Swagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you pass parameters in postman? Please try like this:

[image]

[IValueProvider.GetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt153287(v=vs.118)) uses the specified key to retrieve the value object. When there are multiple `Locales` in the parameter, `MetadataValueModelBinder` will execute multiple times, each time obtaining the value of a `Locales`.

First execution:
[image]

Second exeution:
[image]

Test Result:
[image]